# sqlite keep foreign key when changing table

Tags: sqlite

Database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE accounts (
    id   INTEGER NOT NULL
                 PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR NOT NULL
                 UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE account_info (
    account_id INT REFERENCES accounts (id) ON DELETE SET NULL
                                            ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

INSERT INTO accounts (name) VALUES ('Tom');
INSERT INTO account_info (account_id) VALUES (1);
```

SQLiteStudio generate changing table sql like below and it **works**, the row in account_info still exists after executing below sql.

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = OFF;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `accounts_temp_table`;
CREATE TABLE `accounts_temp_table` AS SELECT * FROM `accounts`;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS accounts;
CREATE TABLE `accounts` (
    `id` INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO `accounts`(`id`, `name`)
SELECT `id`, `name`
FROM `accounts_temp_table`;
DROP TABLE accounts_temp_table;

PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

But, if I use **'alter table**' like below, the row in account_info will be changed to NULL:

```
PRAGMA defer_foreign_keys = OFF;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `accounts_new_table`;
CREATE TABLE `accounts_new_table` (
    `id` INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO `accounts_new_table`(`id`, `name`)
SELECT `id`, `name`
FROM `accounts`;

DROP TABLE `accounts`;
ALTER TABLE `accounts_new_table` RENAME TO `accounts`;

PRAGMA defer_foreign_keys = ON;
```

Is it because I use 'ALTER TABLE' instead of recreating table?

Is there a way to run the whole 1st script in one `sqlite3_exec` call?

Comment: Dropping the accounts table sets off the ON DELETE SET NULL rule since you didn't turn off foreign key support in the second example.

Comment: @Shawn The first example also drops accounts table.

Comment: Your first example disables foreign keys before dropping the table and enables them afterwards.

Comment: My bad, I thought the first lines were the same, let me try again.

Comment: @Shawn you are right, it works if I use 'PRAGMA foreign_keys' in 2nd script.